# Audio / Camera Driver - FriendlyARM Mini2440 - s3c2440

Tags: audio, camera, device-driver, embedded-linux

I am a **newbie** to **embedded linux** and am keen on **learning to write device drivers**. I have got a **FriendlyARM Mini2440** board with me.

Please suggest which device driver would be easier to start learning - **Audio** or **Camera** or something else?

Need suggestions from experts.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is pretty vague as a question.  Usually it is best to pursue something in which you have an interest, or unmet need, or for which there is a partial solution that already exists which you can study and extend.  Failing that, find a solution for a similar problem (driver for a device with some similar properties) and adapt it.  Outside of a classroom environment, very little learning is accomplished by mere study - most progress is made by trying to fulfill a need and learning along the way.

Comment: @chris-stratton Thanks Chris. My interest in embedded linux made me purchase a mini2440. Now I want to learn about device drivers. Hence posted such a question seeking some expert advice. My objective is to make a career out of embedded linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between those 2, I would say that a camera driver would be simpler. Audio drivers in Linux are more complex than most other drivers, and there seems to not be very much documentation on writing them.

Have you read Linux Device Drivers by Jonathan Corbet, Alessandro Rubini, and Greg Kroah-Hartman? That is probably the best way to start.

I'd recommend starting with serial, flash, or ethernet drivers, in that order. Those are common, the code is straightforward, and there's good documentation and examples for them.

Comment: exactly the kind of response I was looking for. Thanks a lot.